# How to add libraries to Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm currently downloaded newest android studio 0.3.2. I've been trying to add libraries for almost 5 hours, and nothing.

I've pressed F4 in the 'Module' where the libraries should go, added the libraries, also in the project structure added the dependencies, and also in build.gradle of the 'Module'. The errors in the IDE stop appearing, but when It 'compiles' it. It keeps telling me, that com.google.gson and other libraries don't exist.

How can I fix It? Or should I use Android studio?. Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

This is the build.gradle file, of the main project.

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
```

And this is the Gradle file o f the 'Module' that gives problems:

```js
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['tests/resources']
}
```

Comment: This suggests that there is something wrong with your build.gradle. Please post it so I can help you.

Comment: Are you using Mac or Windows I use both and they behave differently sometimes ? The issues which were present in previous versions seems to have been resolved. Post your Gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for the [Google Analytics library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources) and the [Gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

Comment: Where can I get a guide on using that syntax and where and how to add those libraries?

Comment: What I can recommend is using the search function on [GitHub](http://github.com) and here on StackOverflow. GitHub allows to filter search results by file name if you specify `path:build.gradle` for example.